# Google sheets перенос изображений (imageOverGrid) в ячейку

Tags: изображения, google-spreadsheet

понадобилось обработать таблицу google sheets с +/-1000 миниатюрных изображений. Большая часть вставлена в ячейки (что есть замечательно для обработки), но отдельные картинки вставлены поверх листа и не поддаются обработке, копированию (адекватно).

В контекстном меню изображений (imageOverGrid) есть функция "присвоить изображению выбранную ячейку"
Ищу возможность используя скрипт получить аналогичный функционал для присвоения изображения в ячейку по getAnchorCell() изображения (по сути циклом перенести все изображения в ячейку под ними).   (информации по подобным решениям не нашлось =( )

была попытка просто перенести привязку изображения (пример ниже) на другой лист. Работает, но ненадежно - отдельные изображения смещаются куда попало =(
код собирает размеры листа, формирует размеры ячеек другого листа, вставляет все данные из ячеек и в конце переносит изображения на новый лист по позициям исходного

```
 function myFunction() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();    
    var F_lRow = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('first').getLastRow();
    var Add_lRow = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('second').getLastRow();
    var Data=spreadsheet.getSheetByName('second').getDataRange().getValues();
    var Str_width=[];
    var Str_high=[];
    
    for (i=1;i<Data.length+1;i++){           // строк
    Str_high.push(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('second').getRowHeight(i));
    }
    
    for (j=1;j<=Data[0].length;j++){
    Str_width.push(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('second').getColumnWidth(j));
    }
    
    Logger.log('строк'+Str_high.length);
    Logger.log(Str_width.length);
    
    
    for (i=0;i<Str_high.length;i++){           
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName('first').setRowHeight(i+F_lRow+1,Str_high[i]);
    
    }
    
    for (i=1;i<=Str_width.length;i++){      
    if (spreadsheet.getSheetByName('first').getColumnWidth(i)<Str_width[i-1]) {
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName('first').setColumnWidth(i,Str_width[i-1])
    }
    
    }
spreadsheet.getSheetByName('second').getDataRange().copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('first').getRange('A'+(F_lRow+1)), {contentsOnly: false} );
    //===========обработчик картинок================
    var images = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('second').getImages();
    var a=0;
    var b=0;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(images[i].getAnchorCell().getA1Notation());
    Logger.log(images[i].getAnchorCell().getColumn() );
    Logger.log(images[i].getAnchorCell().getRow() );
    //images[i].setAnchorCell(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('first').getRange(images[i].getAnchorCell().getColumn(),(images[i].getAnchorCell().getRow()+F_lRow)));
    images[i].setAnchorCell(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('first').getRange(b,a));
    }
    //=====================
    }
```